# macOS SwiftUI Table with more than 10 columns?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I've tried to add the Group {} trick to get more than 10 elements in a Table view, but the fails to compile just like when there is more than 10 elements without the group.

```
    var body: some View {
      Table(viewModel.tableArrayOfStructs, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
        Group {
          TableColumn("One", value: \.One).width(min: 35, ideal: 35, max:   60)
          TableColumn("Two", value: \.Two).width(30)
          TableColumn("Three", value: \.Three).width(50)
          TableColumn("Four", value: \.Four).width(min: 150, ideal: 200, max: nil)
          TableColumn("Five", value: \.Five).width(50)
          TableColumn("Six", value: \.Six).width(min: 50, ideal: 55, max: nil)
          TableColumn("Seven", value: \.Seven).width(88)
          TableColumn("Eight", value: \.Eight).width(88)
          TableColumn("Nine", value: \.Nine).width(20)
          TableColumn("Ten", value: \.Ten).width(50)
       }
       TableColumn("Eleven", value: \.Eleven).width(50)

    }
```

If I add the eleventh+ column also into a new group I get the same issue.  The compiler reports:

```
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions
```

Is there any means to have a table with more than 10 columns short of dropping down to NSViewRepresentable?

Comment: Yeah, your solution of Group is ok but the whole is too complex for the compiler. Try adding explicit types or build it up using smaller functions. It doesn’t have to be part of the view body. The body can call var’s or func’s that return those sub views.

Comment: Thanks.  Note that even if I remove the eleventh column, the compiler still coughs on the group, but if I remove the group and have only 10 items its ok.  Do you have an example of vars of the columns?  Can I create a function that simply returns an array of TableColumns?

Comment: Try playing around with those widths. Might be that that causes the problem. Haven’t used Table much, but it very much feels like a version 1 which it is. Version 2 will hopefully be more robust with more features.

Comment: Try using smaller groups, like 3 groups of 4 each or something. You could also extract the groups into variables, this may help the compiler figure out the types faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple Developer Technical Support was able to help.  They recommended being explicit with the value: type information in the TableColumn to give the compiler some help.  Without explicit type info with or without the group the compiler simply gives up.  I also found that once you add one group, you need to add all TableColumns to be within groups (which have 10 or less TableColums per group)

```
var body: some View {
  Table(viewModel.tableArrayOfStructs, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
    Group {
      TableColumn("One", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.One).width(min: 35, ideal: 35, max:   60)
      TableColumn("Two", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.Two).width(30)
      TableColumn("Three", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.Three).width(50)
      TableColumn("Four", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.Four).width(min: 150, ideal: 200, max: nil)
      TableColumn("Five", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.Five).width(50)
      TableColumn("Six", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.Six).width(min: 50, ideal: 55, max: nil)
      TableColumn("Seven", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.Seven).width(88)
      TableColumn("Eight", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.Eight).width(88)
      TableColumn("Nine", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.Nine).width(20)
      TableColumn("Ten", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.Ten).width(50)
   }
   Group {
     TableColumn("Eleven", value: \ViewModel.TableArrayOfStructs.Eleven).width(50)
   }

}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to use the TableColumnBuilder to help here? I tried using a separate var with this result builder and return type "some TableColumnContent", but then the Table wasn't able to infer some generic parameters

Comment: For anyone looking: this is correct and there _is_ a `Group` extension that makes it conform to `TableColumnContent`, but type-checking is super finicky. You have to be explicit with the base type of your key paths and closure arguments, and you have to have the type right for everything, or else all you get is "can't type-check this expression in reasonable time". Try building your columns right at the `Table` level, which usually gives you usable diagnostics, and move them to a `Group` when you're sufficiently certain your column definitions are right.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not (easily) possible to refactor table columns to another method returning `some TableColumnContent` because you can't hide TableColumnContent's associated type.

Comment: I just found out that when I `Group` `TableColumns` (to be able to have more than 10), I lose sorting for all columns that are not in the first group. Xcode 14.3.1 on Ventura 13.4.1 (c).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the tip of using Group. I was not sure it was going to work on TableColumn the same way as with other View but it works.
In my case, it was not compulsory to enclose all table columns within group.

I also receive the tip from Apple Developer Technical Support to be explicit about the value type: \ViewModel.property instead of .property.

We can also use computed property to generate a TableColumn like this:

```
var firstNameColumn: TableColumn<ViewModel, KeyPathComparator<ViewModel>, Text, Text> {
    TableColumn("Firstname", value: \ViewModel.firstname)
}
```

The first Text refer to the \ViewModel.firstname that generates automatically a text while the second Text is for the label "FirstName"

In some case, when the type cannot be compare, you can replace KeyPathComparator by Never.

For instance for a date:

```
var dateColumn: TableColumn<ViewModel, Never, DateView, Text> {
    TableColumn("Date") {doc in
        DateView(date: doc.date)
    }
}
```

Where DateView is a custom View.

Hope that helps others

Regards

Vincent

Answer (score -2):

An example as requested in the comment (untested).

```
var body: some View {
  Table(viewModel.tableArrayOfStructs, sortOrder: $sortOrder) {
    Group {
      self.foo //since foo has the @VB annotation, these will just be “pasted” in here. 
    }
    self.foobar //not a @VB, so it returns a specific view
    self.bar(count: …)
 }

@ViewBuilder //not always necessary but usually very handy, depending on what you return
var foo: some View {
      TableColumn("One", value: \.One).width(min: 35, ideal: 35, max:   60)
      TableColumn("Two", value: \.Two).width(30)
      TableColumn("Three", value: \.Three).width(50)
      TableColumn("Four", value: \.Four).width(min: 150, ideal: 200, max: nil)
      TableColumn("Five", value: \.Five).width(50)
      TableColumn("Six", value: \.Six).width(min: 50, ideal: 55, max: nil)
      TableColumn("Seven", value: \.Seven).width(88)
      TableColumn("Eight", value: \.Eight).width(88)
      TableColumn("Nine", value: \.Nine).width(20)
      TableColumn("Ten", value: \.Ten).width(50)
   }

var foobar: some View {
  Group {
          TableColumn("One", value: \.One).width(min: 35, ideal: 35, max:   60)
          TableColumn("Two", value: \.Two).width(30)
          TableColumn("Three", value: \.Three).width(50)
  }
}

func bar(count: Int) -> some View
{
   //as with foo, return your sub view
   //annotate with @ViewBuilder if necessary
}
```

Point is, you don’t have to construct your entire view in the view’s body. Depending on programming style, code organisation,semantics, … ; split up your code into other child view structs or (private) vars and funcs within a view struct.

Comment: Thanks.  TableColumn does not conform to View, so the foo variable does not compile.  foobar  does conform to View because of the Group, but adding Group around TableColumns makes the compiler fail to complete with the same error.  Maybe using TableColumnBuilder is required to do anything other than the basic example in the Table documentation.  Sadly, there are few examples of TableColumnBuilder, tho the reference documentation appears complete.