# Sections in a SwiftUI MacOS Table will not build

Tags: swiftui, realm

I am trying to create a Table in SwiftUI for MacOS with sections in the table. The compiler wants me to break it up into sub-expressions, but I dont understand how to do this.

This is the error:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

It happens on the ForEach here:

```
    var theTable: some View {
        ForEach(groupedFlights.keys.sorted()){ key in
            Text("DaySequenceNumber: \(key)")
            Table(groupedFlights[key]){
                TableColumn("FLIGHTNO", value: \.flightNo)
                TableColumn("DATE", value: \.date)
                TableColumn("FROM", value: \.from)
                TableColumn("TO", value: \.to)
                TableColumn("ACREG", value: \.acReg)
                TableColumn("STD", value: \.std)
                TableColumn("STA", value: \.sta)
                
            }
        }
    }

private var groupedFlights: [Int: [Flight]] {
        Dictionary(grouping: showingFlights, by: \.daySequenceNo)
    }
```

The Flight class:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Flight: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable{
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id:ObjectId
    @Persisted var flightNo:String
    @Persisted var date:String
    @Persisted var from:String
    @Persisted var to:String
    @Persisted var acReg:String
    @Persisted var std:String
    @Persisted var sta:String
    @Persisted var daySequenceNo:Int
    @Persisted var crewList:CrewList?
    
    var idString:String{
        id.description
    }
}
```

How can i break down theTable?

Comment: Two questions: can you include this model `CrewList` and, if you take this `\.flightNo` out and replace it with just a temporary string on each property does it work? `TableColumn("FLIGHTNO", value: "test")`. Also, did you verify `groupedFlights.keys.sorted()` resolves to something that makes sense?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Yes I tried a simplified version in the Playground and groupedFlights.keys.sorted() worked fine there.
I commented out all the TableColumns and replaced with a generic. This led to : "Value of optional type '[Flight]?' must be unwrapped to a value of type '[Flight]'", so I might have to look at this.
I'll post the code in a reply as there is not enough characters in a comment.

Comment: This error is usually caused by a typo comment out sections until you find it. Also your model has to conform to identifiable for it to work in a ForEach like that

Comment: It happens when I have more than six columns. I remember seeing something about this on Paul Hudsons channel, but cant find it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in another thread:

[macOS SwiftUI Table with more than 10 columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69874420/macos-swiftui-table-with-more-than-10-columns)

So I added ***as Flight*** to this line:

```
Table(groupedFlights[key]! as [Flight]){
```